# Add application arguments in eclipse on a Blackberry Application

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, arguments

Is it possible to add multiple Application arguments on a Blackberry Application on eclipse? I tried adding one Application argument by specifying it on the Blackberry App Descriptor and it worked well. Now my problem is I want to add one more argument. What I did was to separate it with comma ',' but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put all the arguments in to the *one* field that you have in the BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml file.  They will be combined, and then you can just split them apart in your app.

For example:

```xml
<Properties ModelVersion="1.1.2">
  <General Title="HelloBB" Version="1.0.0" Vendor="BlackBerry Developer" Description=""/>
  <Application Type="BlackBerry Application" 
     MainMIDletName="" 
     MainArgs="-one 1 -two 2 -three 3" 
     HomeScreenPosition="0" 
     StartupTier="7" 
     IsSystemModule="false" 
     IsAutostartup="false"/>
```

I've passed three parameters, separated by switches (parameter **names**):

```
-one 1 -two 2 -three 3
```

Then, in my main program, I have:

```java
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      // Create a new instance of the application and make the currently
      // running thread the application's event dispatch thread.
      try {
         String[] params = StringUtils.split(args[0], " ");
         MyApp theApp = new MyApp();
```

And you can see then that the `params` array has all my switches and parameter values:

[image]

You'll just need some utility function to split the `args[0]` string.  You could start with [this one on blackberry.com](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/String-Manipulation-split-replace-replaceAll/ta-p/620038), but note @EugenMartynov's comment at the bottom of the page about a small bug in the code.